# How to create Class object in .cshtml page MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have create class with function to return DataTable

```
 namespace Office365
 {
    public class Office365
    {
         public DataTable GetQAData()
           {
              return Datatable;
           }  
    }
 }
```

this function use in Controlller and render data using ViewBag.Content like this

In .cshtml

```
       @Html.Raw(ViewBag.QAData)
```

In Controller Code :

```
   using Office365;
   Office365 con = new Office365();

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        DataTable dt = con.GetQAData();
        int i = 1;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
           sb.append("<div></div>")
        }

        ViewBag.QAData = sb.ToString();
```

but is this possible to  call class object on `.cshtml` and render my DataTable into Div? I means directly write code in `.cshtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a ViewModel with a collection of your rows.
Then from the page I will cycle trough it and create the html.
Something like this

```
 public calss DataViewModel
 {
    public IList<MyRow> Rows {get;set;}
 }
```

From controller

```
    var model = new DataViewModel()
    model.Rows = new List<MyRow>();
    DataTable dt = con.GetQAData();
    int i = 1;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
       var row = new MyRow();
       /* populate the the MyRow class */
       Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

From the view

```
    @foreach(var item in Model.Rows)
    {
       <div>@item.MyField</div>
    }
```

I hope you get the idea

Comment: m new comer in MVC. When i use Model in razor page. got Object reference null error. Code `@model WebNexpo.Controllers.DataViewModel
    @foreach(var item in Model.Rows) { @item.ID };` is this wrong?

Comment: It should be right. Maybe you dind't initialized Rows in the controller?. where exactly happen the error

Comment: try to get by debug point show me Model = null. i tell u that m return `View('Index')` in ActionResult. maybe cause by this?

Comment: Yes, you should also pass the model to the view. Another tip. if you don't need to open a view different from the method name omit the view name. Instead of return View("Index", yourModel); use where possible return View(yourModel);

Comment: How u initialized Rows in the Controller?

Comment: this line in the controlelr intialize the Rows `model.Rows = new List<MyRow>();` It refer to MyRow class where you put the fields that you need

Comment: instead initializing rows in the Controller i'd just insert the item row in model.rows.add(item). But thanks men